# Blurry text from identification documents detection and ocr

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, text, ocr

I have a very specific *scene text* detection and parsing problem. I am not even sure if you can say it is an actual *scene text*.

I have extracted a name field from an identity card photo:
[image]

I could immediately start applying some OCR on that image, but i believe a further text localisation could be applied. To achieve this image:[image] **Do you know any of such text localisation algorithms? I have already tried '*FASText by Busta*', '*EAST by argman*' and they work decently. Any algorithms on this specific task?**

After the localisation of the text i think now it is the best time to apply OCR. And now i feel lost. **Which OCR could you recommend to use? I have already tried 'Tesseract' but it just doesn't work well. Is it a better idea to make your own OCR for document characters by using e.g. Tensorflow?**

Comment: You could try performing some image enhancement techniques prior to using the above mentioned OCR algorithms!

Comment: Are there any reasons not to use specialized ID scanning SDKs?

Comment: @ssasa yes, they do not work with low res.

Comment: @LaimonasSutkus Then you have a very challenging task ahead of you :) There are commercial ID scanning SDKs that have invested quite a lot in developing robust scanning including low res.

Comment: I am fully aware of that. Thank you! :) (Im not alone on this long journey haha)

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the contrast of the image. You can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np


def cvt_BGR2RGB(img):
  return cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


def contrast(img,show=False):
  # CLAHE (Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization)
  clahe=cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3., tileGridSize=(8,8))

  lab=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)  # convert from BGR to LAB color space
  l,a,b=cv2.split(lab)  # split on 3 different channels

  l2=clahe.apply(l)  # apply CLAHE to the L-channel

  lab=cv2.merge((l2,a,b))  # merge channels
  img2=cv2.cvtColor(lab, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)  # convert from LAB to BGR
  if show:
    #plot the original and contrasted image
    f=plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
    ax1=f.add_subplot(121)
    img1_cvt=cvt_BGR2RGB(img)
    plt.imshow(img1_cvt)
    ax2=f.add_subplot(122)
    img2_cvt=cvt_BGR2RGB(img2)
    plt.imshow(img2_cvt)
    plt.show()
  return img,img2
```

And maybe then you can use `pyteserract`